# Cannot find jar at libraries

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I do a dependency project for my personal exercise project. Then I want to import `spring-boot-starter-security`, it builds successful and dependency tree shows right, but I cannot find security jars at libraries.

Here is my exercise project pom:

```xml
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Here is my shared-pom which is parent project of above project:

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>*</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

spring.boot.version: 2.1.6.RELEASE

my exercise project dependency tree:

```
[INFO] com.personal:auth:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.18.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:2.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:5.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:5.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:5.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] \- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO]    \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
```

Make sure my local repository has those jars.
My lib:

[image]

UPDATE:
Every time I changed pom then will **reimport** project or exec `mvn clean install`, and always the same result.

Comment: I always reimport project or exex `mvn clean install` or click `import changes` after modifed pom.@Karthikeyan Vaithilingam

Comment: Try `File->Invalidate Caches / Restart ... -> Invalidate and Restart`